# How to turn a buffered file into an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently sending a file to my express server and due to the fact that I am using a cloud service my file is pre processed into a buffer `<buffer 2o 7x 52o...>`. I know I can convert this to text by simply using `JSON.stringify(buffer)` however once its text I can't access the data like buffer.filename etc. So whats the procedure for properly accessing that data?

Data after running buffer.toString() and running json.parse() just throws an error after.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQ2vIfsUjol7BWXhG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testFile.txt"; filename="testFile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Today I went to the beach and then I went to the shore and
then I went to the store and then I went to
------WebKitFormBoundaryQ2vIfsUjol7BWXhG--
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(buffer.toString())` ?

Comment: @cmgchess RIght that was my thought as well and I suppose I should of added this but please check the update above.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the buffer to an object using [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromarray). Or, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (after you [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the buffer) to turn it into an object. After it's an object, it will be easy to access the data.